# Monitoring Amazon EC2 instance data transfer out in an MONTHLY basis

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a use case that I need to limit the maximum data out transfer of an instance in MONTHLY basis. Let say i wish to limit it to 3T. It looks like that the current cloudwatch alarm can only monitor the aggregated SUM of data out transfer but it cannot reset the alarm in a periodic basis.

Is there any tools that could help me to do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iftop can be of use here. I was doing something similar a couple of months back, but needed to gauge the amount of data being transfered. Running iftop (like top but for network connections) in a screen session will show the total amount of data transmitted since you ran iftop.

Failing that, you could use tcpdump (assuming your external traffic is going somewhere specific)